# PHP mail function does not send emails

Tags: javascript, php, email

I have a form and I want people to send the form to their email. So I added mail to the code mail($to, $subject ....).  If I enter a value into $to manually (eg $to = "xxx.example.com"), the email will arrive.  However, this solution is impractical because I need to send email by user input.
I created an alert box with input field using JavaScript:

```
function prompt($prompt_msg){ 
echo("<script type='text/javascript'> var answer = prompt('".$prompt_msg."',); </script>");
$answer = "<script type='text/javascript'> document.write(answer); </script>";
return($answer);
}
$prompt_msg = "Zadejte Váš email:";
$name = prompt($prompt_msg);
```

If I print a value with echo ($name), the email address is displayed, but the email is not sent.
Therefore, I created a multiemail value:

```
$recipients = array ("xxx@yyy.com", $name, "yyy@xxx.com");
```

to email address xxx and email address yyy email arrived, but if I viewed email recipients in yyy's email box instead of xxx, yyy and values from $name it showed this:

```
Recipients - xxx, yyy, scripttype='text/javascript'@ssd3.jh-pro.cz
answer <document.write@ssd3.jh-pro.cz>
/script@ssd3.jh-pro.cz
```

This means that instead of the content of $name, the email is sent to:

```
scripttype='text/javascript'@ssd3.jh-pro.cz,
answer <document.write@ssd3.jh-pro.cz>,
/script@ssd3.jh-pro.cz
```

Do you know why this is happening?
Thank you in advance for your help

```
function prompt($prompt_msg){ 
 echo("<script type='text/javascript'> var answer = 
prompt('".$prompt_msg."',); </script>");
 $answer = "<script type='text/javascript'> document.write(answer); </script>";
 return($answer);
}
$prompt_msg = "Zadejte Váš email:";
$name = prompt($prompt_msg);
$recipients = array("xxx@yyy.cz",$name,"yyy@xxx.com");
$to = implode(',', $recipients);
echo($to);
.
.
.
.
mail($to,$subject,$message,$headers);
```

Comment: A complicated question about sending mail, but I can't find the code that actually sends a mail. Perhaps that's why no mail is send?

Comment: I edited the code. Email is sent, but only if I enter the address in the code ($ to = "xxx@yyy.com). If I want to send an email to $name (the address entered using the alert box), then an email send to **scripttype = ' text/javascript'@ssd3.jh-pro.cz,
answer <document.write@ssd3.jh-pro.cz>
/script@ssd3.jh-pro.cz** instead of being sent to the email address from alert box

Comment: Your `prompt()`, assuming it works, returns javascript. You cannot use javascript in PHP as an email address. Note that Javascript is only processed by a browser, not by PHP. See: [Client Side vs. Server Side](https://www.codeconquest.com/website/client-side-vs-server-side/)

Comment: And is there any way to solve it?
Would you recommend me something?

Answer (score 0):

I assume you're attempting to do this via a web browser. What you're attempting to do is possible, but not in the way you're approaching it.

PHP is a programming language that runs on the server, whereas JavaScript is a programming language that runs in the browser. This is essential to understand: these are two completely different programming languages that are running on two completely separate machines. PHP has no idea what's happening in the user's browser and the user's browser has no idea what's happening in PHP.

In fact, PHP doesn't even know you're generating JavaScript. As far as PHP is concerned, you're just generating a bunch of text and sending it to the user. And the JavaScript doesn't even run until PHP stops executing.

As a result, what's happening in your code is the string `"<script type='text/javascript'> document.write(answer); </script>"` is being stored in `$name` and you're immediately trying to send an email to that string. This all happens before the user is even prompted.

You need to fundamentally alter your workflow here to something like this:

1. Use PHP to generate the JavaScript the user's browser will run.
2. Use the JavaScript on the user's browser to prompt the user for their email.
3. Have the user's browser send the user's email to PHP.
4. Use PHP to process the provided email in a `mail()` call.